# How to match all for a second pattern that follows a particular pattern only?

Tags: regex, pcre

Using [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre), I would like to replace all the `foo` with `bar` only on the lines that starts with `foobar`?

Input:

```
foobar foo   foo                  foo       foo
foobaz    foo   foo            foo   foo foo
```

Output:

```
foobar bar   bar                  bar       bar
foobaz    foo   foo            foo   foo foo
```

I naively tried `\K` like:

```
s/^foobar\Kfoo/bar/g
```

Unfortunately it does not work. For example, with Perl I could do:

```
s/^foobar(.*)/$&=~s#\bfoo\b#bar#gr/gme
```

Is there a way to do it, for example in https://regex101.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine `\K` with a `\G` operator in a regex:

```
(?m)(?:(?!^)\G|^foobar\b)(?:(?!\bfoo\b).)*\K\bfoo\b
```

where `(?:(?!\bfoo\b).)*` [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) is synonymic to `.*?`. If there is not substring to exclude in between `foobar` and `foo`, the `.*?` will perform better, however, in case you want to further restrict the text between `foobar` and `foo`, you will need the token.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ipUA3l/2)

Word boundaries might turn out redudant  if you are not interested in a whole word search.

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `(?:(?!^)\G|^foobar\b)` - match only the end of the previous successful match (with `(?!^)\G` where `\G` matches the start of string or end of the previous successful match, so the `(?!^)` is necessary to exclude position at the start of the string) or the  whole word `foobar` at the beginning of a line (`^` matches the line start position due to `(?m)` flag)
- `(?:(?!\bfoo\b).)*` - match any char other than linebreak symbols, 0+ times, if the char is not starting the `foo` sequence that is a whole word (***or instead*** just replace this part with `.*?` since there is no text to exclude in between `foobar` and `foo`).
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\bfoo\b` - a whole word `foo`

Comment: Ohhh I have seen this pattern involving `\K` and `\G` many times but I am unable to remember it. Actually I have never been able to properly understand it.

Comment: It is true that you can actually use lazy dot matching in this case (see Casimir's answer), no need for the tempered greedy token, because you only have the leading delimiter, and have no closing one. A tempered greedy token would be necessary if there were another string to be excluded in between `foobar` and `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, with this \G *(position after the previous match or start of the string)* based pattern:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|(?m)^foobar\b).*?\K\bfoo\b
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/6vwfQV/1)